# How can i find private ip of Amazon lightsail database if public endpoint enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have enabled public endpoint in lightsail database for connectivity from home.
I want my lightsail instances to connect to lightsail database via private ip from within same region
But i could not find privtate ip in there, unless private ip is not visible if public endpoint is enabled ?

AWS only allows 100GB data transfer per month for LS RDS.
and  there is no way i can find how much data transfer  is used for current month, no metric available

Comment: "I want my lightsail instances to connect via private ip" - connect to where, from where? Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear.

Comment: @Marcin i have added details ,  within same region , lightsail instances to connect to lightsail database via private ip